# Bash script to separate files into directories, reverse sort and print in an HTML file works on some files but not others

Tags: bash, scripting

### Goal

Separate files into directories according to their filenames, run a Bash script that reverse sorts them and assembles the content into one file (I know steps to achieve this are already documented on Stack Overflow, but please keep reading...)

### Problem

Scripts work on all files but two

### State

#### Root directory

```
dos-18-1-18165-03-for-sql-server-2012---15-june-2018.html
dos-18-1-18165-03-for-sql-server-2016---15-june-2018.html
dos-18-1-18176-03-for-sql-server-2012---10-july-2018.html
dos-18-1-18197-01-for-sql-server-2012---23-july-2018.html
dos-18-1-18197-01-for-sql-server-2016---23-july-2018.html
dos-18-1-18232-01-for-sql-server-2012---21-august-2018.html
dos-18-1-18232-01-for-sql-server-2016---21-august-2018.html
dos-18-1-18240-01-for-sql-server-2012---5-september-2018.html
dos-18-1-18240-01-for-sql-server-2016---5-september-2018.html
dos-18-2-release-notes.html
dos-18-2-known-issues.html
```

#### Separate the files into directories according to their SQL Server version or name

```
ls | grep "^dos-18-1.*2012.*" | xargs -i cp {} dos181-2012
ls | grep "^dos-18-1.*2016.*" | xargs -i cp {} dos181-2016
ls | grep ".*notes.*" | xargs -i cp {} dos-18-2-release-notes
ls | grep ".*known.*" | xargs -i cp {} dos-18-2-known-issues
```

**Result (success)**

/dos181-2012:

```
dos-18-1-18165-03-for-sql-server-2012---15-june-2018.html
dos-18-1-18176-03-for-sql-server-2012---10-july-2018.html
dos-18-1-18197-01-for-sql-server-2012---23-july-2018.html
dos-18-1-18232-01-for-sql-server-2012---21-august-2018.html
dos-18-1-18240-01-for-sql-server-2012---5-september-2018.html
```

/dos181-2016:

```
dos-18-1-18165-03-for-sql-server-2016---15-june-2018.html
dos-18-1-18197-01-for-sql-server-2016---23-july-2018.html
dos-18-1-18232-01-for-sql-server-2016---21-august-2018.html
dos-18-1-18240-01-for-sql-server-2016---5-september-2018.html
```

/dos-18-2-known-issues

```
dos-18-2-known-issues.html
```

/dos-18-2-release-notes

```
dos-18-2-release-notes.html
```

#### Variables (all follow this pattern)

dos181-2012.sh

```
file="dos181-2012"
export
```

dos-18-2-known-issues

```
file="dos-18-2-known-issues"
export
```

#### Reverse sort and assemble (assumes /$file exists; after testing all lines of code I believe this is where the problem lies):

```
cat $( ls "$file"/* | sort -r ) > "$file"/"$file".html
```

**Result (success and failure)**

- `dos181-2012.html` has the correct content in the correct order.
- `dos-18-2-known-issues.html` is empty.

### What I have tried

I tried to ignore the two files in the command:

`cat $( ls "$file"/* -i (grep ".*known.*" ) | sort -r ) > "$file"/"$file".html`

**Result: The opposite occurs**

- `dos181-2012.html` is empty
- `dos-18-2-known-issues.html` is not empty

### Thank you

I am completely baffled. Why do these scripts work on some files but not others? (I can share more information about the file contents if that will help, but the file contents are nearly identical.) Thank you for any insights.

Comment: In your __reverse sort and assemble__ process, you are overwriting to the existing `dos-18-2-known-issues.html` file.  Try to change the filename to assemble files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, you question is quite incomplete.  You start great, showing the input files and directories.  But then you talk about variables and $files, but you do not show the code from which these originate.  So I based my answer on the explanation in the first paragraph and what I deduced from the rest of the question.

I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18165-03-for-sql-server-2012---15-june-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18165-03-for-sql-server-2016---15-june-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18176-03-for-sql-server-2012---10-july-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18197-01-for-sql-server-2012---23-july-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18197-01-for-sql-server-2016---23-july-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18232-01-for-sql-server-2012---21-august-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18232-01-for-sql-server-2016---21-august-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18240-01-for-sql-server-2012---5-september-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-1-18240-01-for-sql-server-2016---5-september-2018.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-2-release-notes.html
cp /etc/hosts dos-18-2-known-issues.html

DIRS='dos181-2012 dos181-2016 dos-18-2-release-notes dos-18-2-known-issues'

for DIR in $DIRS
do
    if [ ! -d $DIR ]
    then
        mkdir $DIR
    fi
done

cp dos-18-1*2012* dos181-2012
cp dos-18-1*2016* dos181-2016
cp *notes* dos-18-2-release-notes
cp *known* dos-18-2-known-issues

for DIR in $DIRS
do
    /bin/ls -c1r $DIR >$DIR.html
done
```

- The `cp` commands are just to create the files with something in them.
- You did not specify how the directory names were produced, so I went with the easy option and listed them in a variable ($DIRS).  These could be built based on the filenames, but you did not mention that.
- Then created the directories (first `for`).
- Then 4 `cp` commands.  Your code is very complicated for something so basic.  `cp`, like `rm;mv;ls;...` can do wildcard expansion, so there is no need for complex `grep` and `xargs` to copy files around.
- Finally in the last `for` loop, list the files (`ls`), in 1 column (`-c1`, strictly output formatting), reversed the sort order (`-r`).  The result of that `ls` is sent to a ".html" file of the same name as the directory.

Comment: Your inferences were correct. Your approach solved my issue and, as a bonus, greatly reduced my lines of code. Thank you. Thank you also for the tips on writing better questions.